# Bluemix push notification, got 400 when subscribeToTags

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I called `let push = IMFPushClient.sharedInstance()
        logger?.logInfoWithMessages("subscribe to tags: \(tagsArray)")
        push.subscribeToTags([tagsArray]) { (response: IMFResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in`
to subscribe to a tag, but got 400 from the stacktrace.

```
2016-01-22 16:48:10.648 gschat-swift[44084:5194666] [INFO] [BlueList] subscribe to tags: ["Test"]
2016-01-22 16:48:10.648 gschat-swift[44084:5194666] [INFO] [IMFPushClient] -[IMFPushClient subscribeToTags:completionHandler:] in IMFPushClient.m:314 :: Entering: subscribeToTags.
2016-01-22 16:48:10.650 gschat-swift[44084:5194666] [DEBUG] [IMF] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:44 :: Request url is https://ChatBMS.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions
2016-01-22 16:48:10.653 gschat-swift[44084:5194666] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:194 :: Starting the request with URL https://ChatBMS.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions
2016-01-22 16:48:11.255 gschat-swift[44084:5194362] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:215 :: Request Failed
2016-01-22 16:48:11.256 gschat-swift[44084:5194362] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:216 :: Response Status Code : 400
2016-01-22 16:48:11.257 gschat-swift[44084:5194362] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:217 :: Response Error : Expected status code in (200-299), got 400
2016-01-22 16:48:11.259 gschat-swift[44084:5194362] [ERROR] [IMFPushClient] __51-[IMFPushClient subscribeToTags:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in IMFPushClient.m:350 :: Error while subscribing to tags - Error is: Error Domain=WLAFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo={WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f89b8d8dd10> { URL: https://ChatBMS.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions }, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"message":"Bad Request - Invalid JSON","code":"FPWSE0004E"}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ChatBMS.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions, WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f89b8eb7f00> { URL: https://chatbms.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 22 Jan 2016 16:48:09 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "FAIL FAIL";
    "X-Cf-Requestid" = "cf162009-bd95-46d2-46ca-3cad50a70153";
    "X-Client-IP" = "80.111.218.187";
    "X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 2240839783;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400}
2016-01-22 16:48:11.260 **gschat-swift[44084:5194362] [FATAL] [BlueList] error Error Domain=com.ibm.mobilefoundation.push Code=10 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo={WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f89b8d8dd10> { URL: https://ChatBMS.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions }, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"message":"Bad Request - Invalid JSON","code":"FPWSE0004E"}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ChatBMS.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions, WLAFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f89b8eb7f00> { URL: https://chatbms.mybluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/2b7d11a9-57bf-47e6-8a4c-8aabf044ac8a/subscriptions } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 22 Jan 2016 16:48:09 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Backside-Transport" = "FAIL FAIL";
    "X-Cf-Requestid" = "cf162009-bd95-46d2-46ca-3cad50a70153";
    "X-Client-IP" = "80.111.218.187";
    "X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 2240839783;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400} in subscribe to tags:["Test"]**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see in the error you are providing invalid JSON when attempting to subscribe. If you are trying to subscribe to all available tags, you first need to get the available tags and then use those tags when subscribing. For example:

Swift:

```
push.retrieveAvailableTagsWithCompletionHandler 
{
 (response: IMFResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   let tags = response.availableTags()
   if (tags.count > 0)
 {
   //lets subcribe to all tags for demo purposes
    push.subscribeToTags(tags, completionHandler:
   { (response: IMFResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   })
 }
}
```

Here is documentation providing further insight:

[Tag-based Notifications](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/using_tags.html#tags_main)

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I have "Test" tag on the server, I can see it via the dashboard. then I do push.subscribeToTags(["Test]), tags are the only parameter required. What parameter in the json is not valid? Does it somehow needs the device id? I did register device before subscribe to the tag. I can not subscribe to all the available tags. The mobile only subscribe to a subset of tags.

Comment: Hi Josh,after some testing, I found if the device subscribe to a tag that it has subcribed already, it will fail. For example, if it has subscribed to "tag1", the subscribeToTags(["tag1", "tag2"]) will fail with code 400. At this time, it is still subscribed to "tag1", but not "tag2". So I have to get available tags and only subscribe to the ones in the availables.